# How to extract the optimization model generated in CPLX Studio?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, operations-research

I have an optimization model written in IBM ILOG CPLEX studio. I want the complete model to be written in a standard mathematical programming framework on a text file. How can you do this in CPLEX studio? I can do that while using CPLEX in java, but unable to handle it in CPLEX studio.

Comment: Are you asking how to export in LP format?  This can be done as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=46d47d93-110f-4d97-be39-9c6526240d59&ps=100) (on the IBM developerWorks forum) or [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21401442) (an IBM technote).

Answer (score 1):

You can also set this in a 'settings' file. In your OPL project do 'File -> New -> Settings'. If you open the settings file in OPL Studio, youi will find the stuff for exporting the mathematical model as MPS, LP, SAV etc under 'Language -> Run'. Then you need to add that settings file to your run configuration.

This is quite flexible as you can have several different settings files for different run configurations, and any settings file can be shared across multiple run configurations.